# After changing my UItableView's Height, my scroll does not work again. Cant reach data at the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6

So I am currently very new to ios programming and I am having a bit of an issue with my table view. First I call my web API to get the data I required to populate my table View. Using the data I am able to calculate the number of rows and sections that would exist on my table view. After that I calculate the correct height of my table view. I change the height of my table view and reload the table. It looks like this

```
func tableViewHight(numberOfRows : Int)
{
   let sectionHeight = CGFloat(30) * CGFloat(numberOfSections - 1)
   //This is the height of all the sections in my tableview put together(except the first section since its height will always be 0)
   let tableviewMaximumHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - self.myTableView.frame.origin.y
    //Maximum height would be the distance from the y position of my table view, all the way to the bottom of the device.
  if(tableviewMaximumHeight <= (cellRowHeight * CGFloat(numberOfRows) + sectionHeight))
  {
     self.myTableView.frame.size.height = tableviewMaximumHeight
  }
  else
  {
     self.myTableView.frame.size.height = cellRowHeight * CGFloat(numberOfRows) + sectionHeight
  }

  self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

My table view is able to change height and reload data perfectly. The only Problem is that I am not able to reach the bottom of my table view. I do not know what else to do. I have already check that my table view has

```
myTableView.scrollEnabled = true
myTableView.scrollTop = false
```

If you guys have any advice, I would appreciate it :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem when you manually set the height of a UITableView is that you'll then also have to manually set its content height.

Use Autolayout instead to set the height.

Have an `IBOutlet` for an `NSLayoutConstraint` variable (say, `tableHeightConstraint`) that sets the height of your table, then, in your code:

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableviewMaximumHeight
```

or

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = cellRowHeight * CGFloat(numberOfRows) + sectionHeight
```

Comment: The OP didn't say that he is using Autolayout. You can suggest him :)

Comment: That is what I am suggesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the main root of my problem. The issued lied in my maximumTableviewHeight variable. The problem was that I would the value for this variable in the view did load and apparently the y position of the my table view would always give zero in the view did load. Once the maximum table view height was resolve. The application worked like a a charm.